# React Stateless Component Unable to edit text field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a stateless react component to which some data is being passed.

What I would want:

- populate the data inside text input
- onblur pass the changed value to blur function

Currently am unable to type anything into the text field.

```
// Main file
const dataObj = {
  name: 'Foo'
}

<Component data={dataObj} onBlurFn={onBlurFn()} /> //Assuming onBlurFn exists

//React Component
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const ListView = ({
  dataObj,
  onBlurFn
}) => {
  return (
   <input className="name" type="text" defaultValue={dataObj.name} onBlur={onBlurFn(changedVal)}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's how you use onBlur, try `onBlur={(changedVal) => onBlurFn(changedVal)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's how you use onBlur, try changing it to `onBlur={(changedVal) => onBlurFn(changedVal)}`.

```js
const dataObj = {
  name: 'Foo'
}

const ListView = ({
  dataObj,
  onBlurFn
}) => {
  return (
   <input className="name" type="text" defaultValue={dataObj.name} onBlur={(changedVal) => onBlurFn(changedVal)}/>
  )
}

// fake onBlurFn that prints the value of input onBlur
// please change it to your own implementation
const onBlurFn = (e) => console.log(e.target.value);

ReactDOM.render(<ListView onBlurFn={onBlurFn} dataObj={dataObj} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```